Fetch SQLite database Table Orderby condition in android java
How to conditionally retrieve the data of any table in the SQLite database?
I want to extract condition wise data from a table in the database which I have not been able to successfully for the last 2 days.I am using the below code.
In this activity, the database groups are first loaded into Spinner. When the groups are loaded in the sniper, then by clicking on the name of any group, all the data in that group is loaded in the custom list view in the same activity. Surprisingly groups are loaded in sniper but then circle progress keeps running but nothing else is done and app closes after some time.Please help me for solving this project. Thanks
1- ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.JAVA CODE
      public Cursor fetchAllActiveDetailsUnique(String str) {

    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, 
    CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, 
    CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_name=? AND contact_status=?", new String[]{str, 
     "ACTIVE"}, CONTACT_NUMBER, (String) null, "contact_id ASC");
    }

     public Cursor fetchAllDetails() {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, 
    CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, 
    CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, (String) null, (String[]) null, (String) null, (String) null, 
     (String) null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllDetails(String str, String str2) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, 
     CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, 
   CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_name=? AND 
    contact_status=?", new String[]{str, "ACTIVE"}, CONTACT_NUMBER, 
   (String) null, "contact_id ASC", str2);
  }

2-SelectContactsActivity.JAVA
    public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    public String group_range_;

    public LoadData() {
        SelectContactsActivity.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    public Boolean doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        StringBuilder sb;
        SelectContactsActivity.this.o.clear();
        SelectContactsActivity.this.n.clear();
        ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(SelectContactsActivity.this);
        contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
        int count = (SelectContactsActivity.this.w.equals("") ? contactsDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllDetails() : contactsDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllActiveDetailsUnique(SelectContactsActivity.this.w)).getCount();
        Log.i("Total Contacts found", count + "");
        SelectContactsActivity.this.t.clear();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count) {
            SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity = SelectContactsActivity.this;
            int i2 = selectContactsActivity.E + i;
            List<String> list = selectContactsActivity.t;
            if (i2 > count) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(i + 1);
                sb.append(" - ");
                sb.append(count);
            } else {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(i + 1);
                sb.append(" - ");
                sb.append(SelectContactsActivity.this.E + i);
            }
            list.add(sb.toString());
            List<String> list2 = SelectContactsActivity.this.u;
            list2.add(i + "," + SelectContactsActivity.this.E);
            i += SelectContactsActivity.this.E;
        }
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
        if (SelectContactsActivity.this.t.size() == 0) {
            SelectContactsActivity.this.t.add("0 - 0");
            SelectContactsActivity.this.u.add("0,0");
        }
        SelectContactsActivity.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(selectContactsActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectContactsActivity.t);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SelectContactsActivity.this.l.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        SelectContactsActivity.this.l.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long j) {
                SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity = SelectContactsActivity.this;
                selectContactsActivity.y = selectContactsActivity.u.get(i);
                new LoadListData().execute(new Void[0]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
        if (SelectContactsActivity.this.t.size() > 0) {
            int size = SelectContactsActivity.this.t.size();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = SelectContactsActivity.this.i;
            StringBuilder u1 = this.u();
            u1.append(SelectContactsActivity.this.w);
           if (size > sharedPreferences.getInt(u.toString(), 0)) {
                try {
                    SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity2 = SelectContactsActivity.this;
                    Spinner spinner = selectContactsActivity2.l;
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = selectContactsActivity2.i;
                    spinner.setSelection(sharedPreferences2.getInt("GROUP_RANGE_" + SelectContactsActivity.this.w, 0));
                } catch (Exception unused) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder u() {
        this.group_range_ = "GROUP_RANGE_";
        return null;
    }
}

public class LoadListData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    public StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    public int b;
    public String s;
    public TextView a;

    public LoadListData() {
        SelectContactsActivity.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public Boolean doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        SelectContactsActivity.this.o.clear();
        SelectContactsActivity.this.n.clear();
        ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(SelectContactsActivity.this);
        contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        Cursor fetchAllDetails = contactsDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllDetails(selectContactsActivity.w, selectContactsActivity.y);
        int i = 0;
        while (fetchAllDetails.moveToNext()) {
            fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_ID));
            String string = fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NAME));
            String string2 = fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER));
            fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER));
            fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER));
         fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER)) 
       ;
            ArrayList<NumbersListModel> arrayList = SelectContactsActivity.this.o;
            arrayList.add(new NumbersListModel(i + "", string, string2, Boolean.TRUE));
            i++;
        }
        contactsDetailsDbAdapter.close();
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
        SelectContactsActivity.this.n.clear();
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        selectContactsActivity.n.addAll(selectContactsActivity.o);
        SelectContactsActivity.this.m.notifyDataSetChanged();
        SelectContactsActivity.this.j.invalidateViews();
        SelectContactsActivity.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity2 = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        selectContactsActivity2.B = selectContactsActivity2.n.size();
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity3 = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        selectContactsActivity3.C = selectContactsActivity3.n.size();
        this.J(new StringBuilder(), SelectContactsActivity.this.B, " Contacts Selected", 
       SelectContactsActivity.this.A);
        SelectContactsActivity selectContactsActivity4 = SelectContactsActivity.this;
        selectContactsActivity4.z.setChecked(selectContactsActivity4.C != 0);
        SelectContactsActivity.this.mProgress.cancel();
    }

    private void J(StringBuilder stringBuilder, int b, String s, TextView a) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
        this.b = b;
        this.s = s;
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public SelectContactsActivity() {
    new ArrayList();
    new ArrayList();
    this.v = "";
    this.w = "";
    this.x = "";
    this.y = "";
    this.B = 0;
    this.C = 0;
    this.D = 0;
    this.E = 0;
    this.F = 0;
}

private void showContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_CONTACTS") 
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"}, 100);
    }
}

public void GetGroup() {
    this.q.clear();
    this.r.clear();
    this.s.clear();
    GroupDetailsDbAdapter groupDetailsDbAdapter = new 
         GroupDetailsDbAdapter(SelectContactsActivity.this);
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.open();
    Cursor fetchAllBatchDetails = groupDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllBatchDetails();

    while (fetchAllBatchDetails.moveToNext()) {
        @SuppressLint("Range") String group_name_str = fetchAllBatchDetails.getString( 
       fetchAllBatchDetails.getColumnIndex("group_name"));
        GetGroupDetails("group_id", this.q);
        SaifStringS = "group_id" + this.q;
        GetGroupDetails(GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, this.r);
        GetGroupDetails(GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, this.s);

        this.s.add(0, group_name_str);
        this.r.add(0, group_name_str);
        this.q.add(0, "0");
    }


    groupDetailsDbAdapter.close();
}

private void GetGroupDetails(String group_id, List<String> groupListP) {

    this.group_id = group_id;
    this.groupListP = groupListP;
}


@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void NextMethod() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mode_option);
    ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeImageView)).setOnClickListener(view -> 
      dialog.dismiss());
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mode1Button)).setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SelectContactsActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("GROUP_ID", SelectContactsActivity.this.v);
            intent.putExtra("GROUP_NAME", SelectContactsActivity.this.x);
            SelectContactsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mode2Button)).setOnClickListener(new 
      View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SelectContactsActivity.this, 
        MessageFastActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("GROUP_ID", SelectContactsActivity.this.v);
            intent.putExtra("GROUP_NAME", SelectContactsActivity.this.x);
            SelectContactsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(-1, -2);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(17170445);
    dialog.show();
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void OverlayDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_overlay);
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enableButton)).setOnClickListener(new 
      View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            StringBuilder u = this.u("package:");
            u.append(SelectContactsActivity.this.getPackageName());
            SelectContactsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(new 
      Intent("android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION", Uri.parse(u.toString())), 
      SelectContactsActivity.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        private StringBuilder u(String s) {
            return null;
        }
    });
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton)).setOnClickListener(new 
      View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = SelectContactsActivity.this.p.edit();
            edit.putBoolean(PreferencesConstants.SessionManager.OVERLAY_PERMISSION_STATUS, 
   false);
            edit.commit();
            SelectContactsActivity.this.NextMethod();
        }
    });
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(-1, -2);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(17170445);
    dialog.show();
    }


No error shows. This screen you can see.


